# FastCGI Error in MAMP Pro When Uploading Files In Craft CMS

Tags: mamp, fastcgi, mamp-pro, mod-fastcgi

I get errors when trying to upload files to a local install of a Craft CMS site i run through MAMP Pro v 4.0.5.

The ajax call to upload returns a 500 error code, and the apache log has the following:

```
[Mon Oct 10 08:22:47 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers
(0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.25.fcgi",
referer: http://healthchase2.dev/admin/assets
```

I tried turning off the fastcgi_module from the APache seciton of the control panel for MAMP Pro. But I still get the error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running into the same issue in Mamp 4 and managed to resolve by updating the PHP ini. Although Mamp comes with its own version of imagick I had to add the line `extension=imagick.so` to my ini file which seems to have fixed the problem.

Cheers

Cole

Comment: PS you might also have Imagick disabled by default in the PHP settings for Mamp 4 in the GUI

Comment: Uncommenting extension=imagick.so in php.ini with MAMP resolved this issue for me too. Thank you!